# Botón con comentario estándar para preguntas de baja calidad

Tags: característica-nueva

Es habitual que lleguen preguntas con muy baja calidad y que no cumplen unos mínimos para que sean útiles a la comunidad.

¿Sería interesante añadir un botón que añada un comentario estándar con 'mírate esto y esto otro para mejorar tu pregunta'? En multitud de preguntas veo comentarios similares y eso nos hace perder tiempo y esfuerzo.

Respuesta tipo que se podría añadir mediante el botón que podría estar disponible para personas con algunos privilegios o para todo el mundo:

> Tu pregunta no cumple los mínimos del sitio. Por favor, mira la [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para saber [qué puedes preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [qué tipo de preguntas debes evitar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) y [cómo incluir un ejemplo ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

El botón podría rellenar el texto del comentario sin llegar a publicarlo por si, por lo específico de la pregunta, es necesario añadir o quitar algo al comentario estándar. Creo que ese botón ayudaría en el 90% de las preguntas de baja calidad.

EDIT: jajaja, acabo de usar el comentario estándar en una pregunta nueva... https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40505/how-to-secure-queries-in-meteor-js

Comment: Relacionado: [Lista de comentarios para ayudar a los nuevos usuarios](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/475/83). Hay una aplicación que lo hace: [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](http://stackapps.com/q/2116/20467).

Comment: Gracias. Lo añado a mis favoritos.